# Understanding this [param, value] = line.split(":", 1) in Python

Tags: python-3.x

SO I am a absolute beginner with less than 2 weeks of learning Python 3. However I do believe that I have learned a lot in the last 2 weeks.

My current goal is to connect to the IG API to create an automated trading app.

So far I have managed to authenticate and received some tokens to connect to their API

However, their Streaming API which produce live prices is done through a server called Lightstreamer. I have managed to connect to their server and created a session using Request library

The problem right now is to print out the data/value from the Response.

Anyways, this is what I got from looking around. Could you guys please tell me what this block of code does ? specifically variable by variable, function by function, value by value.

```
session_id = None
control_link = None
streaming_i = streaming_i.iter_lines(chunk_size=80, decode_unicode=True)

for line in streaming_i:
    print("line", line)
    if ":" not in line:
        continue
    [param, value] = line.split(":", 1)
    if param == "SessionId":
        session_id = value
    if param == "ControlAddress":
        control_link = value
    if session_id and control_link:
        break
```

Specifically this code

```
[param, value] = line.split(":", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this code simply tries to set two control variables by reading a stream of text that looks like

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
key3:value3
...
```

It first checks if the line contains a colon, then splits the line into key and value based on that colon, and finally checks to see if the key is relevant to us, filling in the corresponding control variable we're trying to find. It continues doing this for each line until both control variables are set.

```
# initialize variables we'll want to use later
session_id = None
control_link = None
# get an iterator through this stream
streaming_i = streaming_i.iter_lines(chunk_size=80, decode_unicode=True)

# iterate through each line of that iterator
for line in streaming_i:
    print("line", line)                  # print what the line looks lik3
    if ":" not in line:                  # if the line does not contain a ':', 
        continue                         #    then skip it
    [param, value] = line.split(":", 1)  # see below
    if param == "SessionId":             # determine what the parameter is,
        session_id = value               #    and set the appropriate control variable
    if param == "ControlAddress":
        control_link = value
    if session_id and control_link:      # once we've read enough lines to set both control variables,
        break                            #    we stop reading
```

As for the line you're confused about, it's simple *multiple assignment*:

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

`str.split()` returns a list of substrings, that you get from splitting the given string on the given separator character. In this case, the optional argument `maxsplit` is provided, which says how many separators to consider. So here it stops after only the first `:` separator.

So, as given, `line.split(":", 1)` will always return a 2-tuple. The syntax used here simply assigns the first value in that 2-tuple to `param` and the second value in it to `value`. The square brackets around `param, value` are entirely useless and can be removed - arguably they're meant to make it more clear that the returned values from `line.split(...)` are assigned to the *corresponding* variables, but it ends up being more confusing than just not including them. Normally you would use `()` for that instead of `[]`.

---

If you're ever confused about what a function does, then you can run a python console and put in the command `help(function)`. In this case, you know `line` is a string, so you put in `help(str.split)` and it shows you the documentation for the method `split()`:

```
split(self, /, sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
    Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.

    sep
      The delimiter according which to split the string.
      None (the default value) means split according to any whitespace,
      and discard empty strings from the result.
    maxsplit
      Maximum number of splits to do.
      -1 (the default value) means no limit.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can vaguely understand it. Though, would not be able to explain it to myself this clear as you did and therefore this really helped !